# GNU Binutils ld Final Link Error: file truncated

Tags: gnu, ld

trying to manually link some object file archives (.a) files, no obvious warnings besides overlay symbols not being in segment (this compiled in a different configuration so I wasn't concerned), now with different section sizes, I'm getting a
`final link failed: file truncated`

Any ideas?

Tried running ld with verbose flags and checking the linker map output, but no further information was emitted.